# Subview is not resizing with the size changes of superView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

I have a `superView` and I created a new `View` to use as a subview in my code.

Notify Status View is the superView and Driver InfoView is subView:

[image: Notify Status View is the superView and Driver InfoView is subView]

But when I make changes to the size of NotifyStatusView, they changes work with every item in superView except Driver Info View:
2 different sizes of the superView:

[image: 2 different sizes of the superView]

[image: 2nd Size]

The only thing I can think of is that I added the Driver View as a new View and drag and dropped it in to the SuperView.

Comment: self.view.layoutIfNeeded() after you resize your view

Comment: What constraints do you create in your subview?

Comment: i am providing no constraints in my subview

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com It worked. Thank you

Comment: @SarmadZaheer i have added it as the answer. Please accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding the comment as the answer:

you need to call layoutIfNeeded() to tell your view to update the layout changes.

```
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```